# Salesforce missing records when using Bulk API 2.0

Tags: salesforce

We are using the Salesforce Bulk API 2.0 query job to replicate changes in our SF instance (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_create_job.htm) and upload the records to our warehouse.
We use the following query to pull the data:

`SELECT id,... FROM Lead WHERE systemModStamp > <last_sync_date>`

Where last_sync_date is the maximum systemModStamp timestamp that exist in our warehouse - basically pulling all records that have been modified/updated since the last sync.

Lately we have noticed some of the records in the Lead object are missing - we can view them using the SF webapp but they are missing when filtering based on the systemModStamp field, even when the timestamp we filter by is before the record was even created.
When filtering on that record explicitly using the query:

`SELECT id,... FROM Lead WHERE id = <lead_id>`

Where lead_id is the record id that we are missing, we do get the record we are missing in the result, which probably rules our permission problems - this also works using the `createddate` field.

It does not look like the record we are missing is any different to any other record or has any flags that might cause this behaviour.

We tried changing the API version but it didn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing something similar at this moment. While I do not know the underlying problem, I do have a theory. Could the following be the case:

- insert or update of record takes place; id is set, systemModStamp is set; the transaction is not yet committed
- one or more other actions take place - that are committed
- we invoke the API to retrieve records based on the previous last id or systemModStamp value; we will find all records that satistfy this condition and are already committed. We get a new (high water mark)  and/or systemModStamp.
- the first change that was still pending is now committed and the changed or new record becomes visible to the API
- next time we invoke the API with the new  or the new high watermark systemModStamp value to filter we do NOT retrieve the record - because its ID is lower (was assigned earlier) than the  and/or its systemModStamp is earlier than the previous API invoke time or the high water mark value for systemModStamp.

So my theory is that the small time between the DML statement (which sets the Id and systemModStamp ) and the actual commit (which makes the record visible) (possibly combined with other transactions that start later and complete earlier) can cause this record retrieval logic to not be watertight.

We will further investigate this theory. Our workaround now will be to query with a systemModStamp value that is earlier than we would want it to be, retrieving potential duplicates (records that we have processed before) but also getting the records we are now missing out on. We need to cater for the duplicates.